# Modify .htaccess for query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my working directory

```
das
|__views
   |__admin
   |__doctor
   |__user
      |__find-doctor.php
      |__process.php
      |__show-result.php
   |__index.php(landing page)
|__index.php(routing)
|__.htaccess
```

The .htaccess I have right now is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /das/index.php [L]
```

I need to modify the htaccess file to send query strings like

```
localhost/user?doctor-id=2
```

so that I can use the id from URL for querying database

Comment: These GET parameters are per default preserved by the rewriting rules. You can already use them in PHP. If not, so if you have some very exotic setup, then add the documented `QSA` flag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @BadHorsie it doesn't answer my question specifically but I got the idea of how the system works thanks

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^index/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-([0-9]+) .php?user=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 $get_param_one = $_GET['user'];
 $get_param_two = $_GET['id'];

 echo $get_param_one;
 echo $get_param_two;
 ?>
```

Example URL: https://example.com?user=doctor&id=who
get_param_one = doctor
get_param_two = who